# Why do I get a query string in my HTML path while using Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I've got an AngularJS project, and I'm using `$routeProvider` and `$locationProvider` with `ngView` to swap out parts of the DOM as necessary.  I'm running Angular 1.0.6.

However, when I define a link in my document like `<a href="#!/view2">View 2</a>`, it gets turned into `?q=home/#!/view2` when I click on it.

Why does the query string get added?  How can I prevent that?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the "#!" notation. I've used angular routing and the format is always /#/pageName. What version are you using? What is your server env?

Comment: It's the standard Google uses to index Ajax websites.  I'm setting it using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");`.  See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1 for details.

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr? I have not experienced what you describe so  I'm wondering what you mean with "using `$routeProvider` and `$locationProvider`".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is AngularJS duplicating the query string in my route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134738/why-is-angularjs-duplicating-the-query-string-in-my-route)