# Why is AngularJS duplicating the query string in my route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-routing

I am using hash-based navigation in my AngularJS app rooted at `/`.

If a user navigates to my app like this:

`http://example.com/?foo`

A moment after the page loads, something (possibly Angular) is causing the address bar to look different than I expected.

What I saw:

`http://example.com/?foo#/?foo`

What I expected to see:

`http://example.com/?foo#/`

Why is this happening, and can I turn it off?

Comment: can you show the angular routing file content?  not sure that would help but maybe...

Comment: I just ran into this problem and was sure it was going to be difficult to find a solution. But injecting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd wager you need to be in 'html5 mode' to not have the hash fragment... though I'm uncertain.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

In your app configuration, you can mess with that config param and it'd probably get rid of it.

Comment: I'm not asking about the hash fragment. I'm asking about the duplicated query string to the right of the hash. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: To be clear, angular always duplicates everything with the hash fragment in my experience. So if you're not in HTML5 mode, you're going to see the duplication, because angular can update "searches" as they're called.

Comment: if you update your answer to include the info from your comment above (and it's actually a true assertion), I'll mark it as the correct answer. That's just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be duplicating the hash with the path.

Check out the $location service. It has both path() and hash() methods. The second, duplicated part is the hash, the first part is the path.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using html5 mode, all of Angular's part of the URL appears in the fragment. The problem is that Angular doesn't know about the base part of the URL (perhaps the ?foo was needed just to get Angular to load) so it won't attempt to manipulate it, it just puts its own stuff on as a fragment.

I suggest the best thing would be to check `$window.location.search` for a query string, and if you find one do the redirect to the URL you actually want yourself. You'll still need to do that redirect by assigning to `$window.location` rather than `$location` and it will force your angular app to reload but at least you'll end up where you want to get to.

Alternatively you could reconfigure your web server to make the appropriate rewrite, but you may not want to or be able to do that.

Or you tell your users to only use URLs they got from the app, not to try to make them up for themselves.